# Jquery ajax - price not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery function that has an ajax call. I can't get the total price to come up even though it should be working. The class .cart-price is within .cart-body so I don't think its an issue with the template.

```
      function refreshCart(){
        console.log("in current cart")
        var cartTable = $(".cart-table")
        var cartBody = cartTable.find(".cart-body")
        // $(cartBody).empty()
        //cartBody.html("<h1>Changed</h1>")
        var productRows = cartBody.find(".cart-product")
        var currentUrl = window.location.href
        var refreshCartUrl = '/api/cart/'
        var refreshCartMethod = "GET";
        var data = {};
        $.ajax({
          url: refreshCartUrl,
          method: refreshCartMethod,
          data: data,
          success: function(data){
            console.log("success")
            console.log(data)
            if (data.products.length > 1){
                productRows.html(" ")
                $(cartBody).empty()

                $.each(data.products, function(index, value){
                  console.log(value)
                    cartBody.append("<tr><td>" + value.name + "</td><td>" + value.price + "</td></tr>")
                })

                // console.log(data.total)
            cartBody.find(".cart-total").text(data.total)
            } else {
              window.location.href = currentUrl
            }

          },
        error: function(errorData) {
          console.log("error")
          console.log(errorData)
        }
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: Please, debug your code, pinpoint where this goes wrong and then ask a more precise question.

Comment: Have you checked that the AJAX call is being made? And that it's successful? Are the `console.log()` calls displaying, and showing the correct information?

Comment: The ajax call is being made. I can use console.log to check the value and it is returning the correct total.

Comment: `even though it should be working` Can you post the value `data` contains?

Comment: Stepping through your code, does your code goes into your `if (data.products.length > 1){` ? If `console.log(value)` is printed within the `each` then we need to see the markup `var cartBody = cartTable.find(".cart-body")` refers to. Please make a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the relevant code. Obviously you can hard-code the content of `data` when creating the demo code but it might already help you solve your problem if it is a selector issue.

Comment: The issue is that (cartBody).empty is clearing the whole body each time including the price (cart.total) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(cartBody).empty() was clearing everything in the table body. The solution was to create a new HTML table row outside of the table body.